# Any equivalent linux package repository mirror to Windows Server

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, windows-server

Is there any way to host windows update server for software updates? I am aware of WSUS, but it seems that not used for public purpose.

Answer (score -1):

- There is [SCCM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_Center_Configuration_Manager) which is distributed by Microsoft itself.
- [InTune](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Intune) (again offered by MS) is a cloud based solution and could
  also be useful, depending on your specific requirements.
- Maybe [Opsi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opsi) is worth a look, too. It uses Linux servers to manage
  Windows clients. Some parts of it (the ones you seem to be interested
  in) are free to use and open source.